# Cannot read imported csv file with excel in UTF-8 format after python scraping

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, encoding

I have a csv file encoded in utf-8 (filled with information from website through scraping with a python code, with str(data_scraped.encode('utf-8') in the end for the content)).
When I import it to excel (even if I pick 65001: Unicode UTF8 in the options), it doesn't display the special characters.
For example, it would show \xc3\xa4 instead of ä

Any ideas of what is going on?

Comment: Try encoding it as 'utf-8-sig', which is used in some MS products instead of vanilla utf-8

Comment: Thank you for your proposition, but it doesn't work, the output is the same.

Comment: Can you share some of the offending rows from the csv?  Ideally as raw bytes, so we can see what's there.  (for example, the output of `open('myfile.csv', 'rb').read()`, or at least enough of it to reproduce the problem).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The reason is that in the original code, I removed items such as \t \n that were "polluting" the output with the replace function. I guess I removed too much and it was not readable for excel after.

In the final version, I didn't use
str(data_scrapped.encode('utf-8') but
data_scrapped.encode('utf-8','ignore').decode('utf-8')

then I used split and join to rempove the "polluting terms":
string_split=data_scrapped.split()
data_scrapped=" ".join(string_split)